# How to install Camelot package in Python?

Tags: python, python-camelot

I need to convert tabular PDFs to CSV. I tried with everything like tabula, pdfminer etc... but nothing seems to give me desired output.

I came across Camelot and want to give it a go but not able to install it over Anaconda. I am trying with `conda install -c conda-forge camelot-py` but it does not seem to return console control.

How can I proceed further with this?

Comment: add the error you are getting!

Comment: What does "not able to install" mean? That is about as descriptive as "my computer doesn't work", please be specific.

Comment: @ParthS007 - there is no specific error I get during installation, the process just does not get completed untill manually stopped

Comment: @Roope I am trying to install the Camelot package over anaconda using the command "conda install -c conda-forge camelot-py", but as I mentioned above, the process do-sent completes and I have to manually stop it.
is there any other way you can suggest on how to install the package?

Comment: You can install dependencies (https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install-deps.html#install-deps) then use pip (https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install.html#using-pip)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, we need to install Ghostscript first, that too the GhostScript application is needed to be installed and added to the path in order for it to work

Answer (score 1):

If you are on google colab, create a new notebook and install it like this. This one handles Ghostscript issues as well.

```
!pip install camelot-py[cv]
```